# db2 select * where by columnname from other table

Tags: db2

I want to find all the attributes of a particular table where their values are not null. I tried the following approach, but in the WHERE condition I can not access s.colname. Can you help me ?

```
SELECT s.colname
FROM syscat.columns s
WHERE s.tabschema = 'IMDB' and s.tabname = 'MOVIES' and EXISTS (SELECT count(s.colname) FROM imdb.movies WHERE s.colname NOT NULL)
```

Comment: You ever seen a table with a null column name? Have a look in sys_columns for how not allowed/ allowed null is stored.

Comment: its not definded! We have to check if a value is not null and if not null then we have to alter this table ....

Comment: oh now I get it. Don't know DB2 in SQL Server I would have used a cursor through syscolumns to build a string of sql and then executed it fir each column. You can't do it like you are. Stop with the exclamation marks, it's rude!

Comment: A cursor is way of looping through the rows of a query and putting the row values in variables. So you get the column names, each one into say a variable column_name, then build some sql e.g sql = 'Select ' + @column_name + 'from imdb.Movies' then exec(sql) would run it.

Comment: <code>
SELECT s.colname AS column_name, (SELECT count('+ [AD]column_name +') FROM imdb.movies WHERE '+ [AD]column_name +' IS NULL ) AS t2
FROM syscat.columns s
WHERE s.tabschema = 'IMDB' and s.tabname = 'MOVIES'
</code>

Comment: All I can say is that would give you a two column result, with column name and the query string in Sql Server, it wouldn't execute the associated query to get the result.  So unless this is some fun DB2 language feature, you still need a cursor or a database function.